# Adding an image on top of a div with a BG color

Tags: html, css, background

So I'm using Square Space for the first time to build a website for my wedding.

Right now, when you scroll down on the homepage, there is some parallax scrolling that happens to bring up the next section. This is what it looks like:

[image]

Instead of having that harsh line that is the container of the next div's content, I would like to add another row of trees on top of that div so it would look something like this:

[image]

Then the trees move upwards and off screen as you scroll down.

So far, it looks like I can only customize the CSS and not the actual HTML files. I am unsure of how to do this in CSS.

When I inspect the div, this is what comes up in the CSS:

```
#content-wrapper .content {
width: 100%;
background-color: #54535f;
position: relative;
z-index: 50;
}
.content.has-main-image {
box-shadow: 0 0 75px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}
```

Can anyone help with the code for this? I could easily do it if I had access to the HTML and could just make another div, but I have no idea how to do it with CSS.

Thanks!

Comment: does the first image (trees) have `fixed` background attachment? if you send us a live demo, it would be easier to help you

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't live yet since I was in the trial. I just went and purchased it, so here it is live: http://www.meetusinthemountains.net/

Ignore all the placeholder stuff. I literally only did the header so far haha

Comment: so as I suspected, the background has `fixed` attachment, making the parallax effect. At this point you have to decide if you want to disable that particular parallax effect or just fade the other box like this > http://puu.sh/noUJL/bd1042768d.jpg

Comment: I just thought of something else: you could keep the background fixed but separate the black trees (front layer) from it and then have the black trees as a background of another element, since you cannot edit the actual HTML, we could use a pseudo selector (like `:before`) which I could explain an a formal answer, if you can separate the trees.

Comment: Yep, all the trees are on a separate layer (I made the image originally) so I could.

Comment: Ok, would be nice to send me the separate black trees (PNG) and original background without black trees (JPEG) to use in my answer

Comment: Dark trees - http://imgur.com/xx72pbB

BG - http://imgur.com/BJ6HlzF

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104815/discussion-between-kelsey-kronmiller-and-aziz).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is by creating a separate layer for the dark trees as discussed in the comments. Since you cannot modify the HTML structure, we'll create a `pseudo selector` for the `#content-wrapper .content` div which will essentially be a background layer that gets the dark trees, while the body gets the background without the trees.

First step is changing the body background to the image without the dark trees.

Then, add this CSS:

```
#content-wrapper .content:before {
    content: ""; /* required for psuedo selectors to work */
    display: block; /* makes sure element is a block box */
    position: absolute; /* make sure element does not affect layout */
    left: 0; right: 0; width: 100%; /* makes sure element stretches */
    height: 400px;
    top: -350px; /* offset element from content box so it appears above it */
    z-index: -1; /* make sure element does it overlap other elements */
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/xx72pbB.png) no-repeat 50% 44%;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Also, I noticed that the`background-color` in content boxes do not match the dark trees color, the correct value should be: `#585862`

```
#content-wrapper .content {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #585862; /* was #51535c */
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1; /* was 50, change to 1 to prevent overlapping */
}

.content-inner {
    background-color: #585862; /* was #51535c */
    max-width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 100px 8%;
}
```

---

**Pros**

- Keeps parallax effect
- No modification of HTML structure
- Adds depth

**Cons**

- Slight increase in page load time (since making two http requests)

---

End result should look like this:

[image: dark trees slide]